# Reflected random walk

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, random-walk

Suppose that $X_n$ is a reflected (in 0) random walk with parameter $\theta$.

So $X_{n+1}-X_n = 1$ with probability $\theta$ , and -1 with probability $1-\theta$ when $X_n \geq 1$, if $X_n=0$ then $X_{n+1}=1$ with probability 1.

I would like to know if we can compute $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{X_0+X_1+...+X_n}{n+1}$ when $\theta < \frac{1}{2}$? (i guess the limit is $\infty$ when $\theta=\frac{1}{2}$).

Thank you

Comment: This is a positively recurrent Markov chain with an explicit stationary distribution $\pi$ hence the limit exists and is equal to $\sum\limits_nn\pi(n)$.

Comment: Thnak you for your answer. However, in my case the real reflected random walk doesn't get +1 or -1 with probability $\theta$ (resp $1-\theta$) but gets +a   or -b for a particular couple (a,b). Suppose the markov chain is still positively recurrent, it seems very difficult to compute the stationary distribution. Is it possible?

Comment: New question? Then new post.

Comment: By the way: "it seems very difficult to compute the stationary distribution"... Well, it is not, actually.

Comment: Ok thank you, i just posted a new question.